# How to set splash timeout in scrapy-splash?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I use [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to crawl web page, and run splash service on docker.

commond:

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --max-timeout 3600
```

But I got a 504 error.

```
"error": {"info": {"timeout": 30}, "description": "Timeout exceeded rendering page", "error": 504, "type": "GlobalTimeoutError"}
```

Although I try to add `splash.resource_timeout`, `request:set_timeout` or `SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050?timeout=1800.0'`, nothing changed.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use `scrapy-splash` package and set the timeout in `args` parameter of `SplashRequest` like this:

```
yield scrapy_splash.SplashRequest(
    url, self.parse, endpoint='execute',
    args={'lua_source': script, 'timeout': 3600})
```

It works for me.

Comment: I got error 400 from this setting. I don't know why

Comment: This does not really explain why its timing out though. Setting the timeout to 3600 is just hiding the errors... Something is still going seriously wrong if it takes 3600 seconds to execute.

Comment: Ahh, I got error 400 if I set the timeout more than the max timeout set when running the Splash server. The default max timeout is 90